# Arduino Reverse Engineering Sky Remote IR output data

Tags: arduino, reverse-engineering, arduino-uno, circuit, infrared

Project:
Convert an existing Sky remote into a Bluetooth HID device (to control PC)

Steps:

- Remove IR LED
- Use existing remote circuit
- Decode output details
- Translate output to keyboard button press
- Use bluetooth HC-05 with RN42 firmware for Bluetooth HID capabilities
- Sit back and control PC with sky remote :)

Problem:
Using the existing circuit, I want to read the output values sent by the controller to the IR LED. I am not sure how to go about this.

I have soldered a wire to the (+) positive terminal of the IR LED and have attempted to read it using the following sketch code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 12;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

My logic was that if the data being sent to the IR LED is the same as that being read by receiver, I could be able to read that data directly from the circuit without the IR LED / IR receiver. However this has not really worked, results I am receiving are irregular.

When I press a button, most of the time data is printed on the serial monitor, however this data is not consistent. Sometimes when I press a button no data is printed. Serial monitor results for pressing the 'Right' button 5 times:

```
1915173721
1967414055
```

Some more results when pressing other arrow buttons:

```
749184133
4255908178
2645846893
3808018029
1874349767
489623152
4272685797
1488398475
2816865927
1510598699
1286666972
881703980
1976667380
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? I think so :/

Any advice would be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: do you have common GND? what's the voltage?

Answer (score 0):

The signal outputs to IR LED is coded pulses modulated with a specific frequency of carrier. For most of remote controllers, the carrier frequency is 38KHz. But you can still find other carrier frequencies like 40KHz, or even 56KHz.

The IR receiver is designed to receive IR signals modulated with a specific frequency of carrier. The receiver will then remove the carrier and only output the coded pulses.

So when you remove the IR LED and read the signals directly, you do not get the same result as you read from the IR receiver output.

You need to have some filtering circuit to remove the carrier before feeding the signal into your serial reader.